# Sequence with infinite limit

Tags: limits, soft-question

Most definitions that I see about sequences that diverge to positive infinity are like

"We say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ if for every number $M>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $a_n>M$ whenever $n>N$."

Is there a reason to require $M>0$ ?

Comment: None at all. Just a matter of habit, I suppose.

Comment: Of course not.  When we say for every $\epsilon>0$ we can say $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, for example. Only small $\epsilon$ matters. Similarly only large positive $M$ matters here.

Comment: I find it fun that this "bug" perpetuates.

Comment: +1, by the way.

Comment: When you consider the positive number M, you also prove the case the term is bigger than the negative number.

Comment: @WeijunYin: I know, but this is not necessary. You might as well require $M>22^\pi$.

Comment: Psychological and pedagogical reasons, but not logical ones.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss: I admit the psychological argument: setting $M>0$ is "reassuring". But at the same time it is "antipedagogical" by introducing a wrong requirement - unless the goal is to make students question it :-).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn’t say they were *good* pedagogical reasons 

Comment: @MichaelWeiss: I didn't say you said :)